# PHP array saving each character in a separate field instead of separating by the comma

Tags: php, arrays

Good day, new to PHP here

Using a form with a drop down, I want to send an array of 2 values, a Int and an String
such as "[Int,String]",

however PHP is creating an array of each character which ends up
["[","i","n","t",",","s","t","r","i","n","g","]"]

On the PHP side, how do I get the array to only have the 2 elements, the int and string?

HTML:

```html
<label class="large-label"><b>Course: </b><span class="small-label"></span><br></label>
<select name="course" id="course">
  <option id="0" value="" selected="" disabled="">« Please Select a Course »</option>
  <option id="1" value="[0,all]">All</option>
  <option id="2" value="[1,Course1]">Course1</option>
  <option id="3" value="[2,Course2]">Course2</option>
  <option id="4" value="[3,Course3]">Course3</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
$courseId = $_POST['course']; 
print_r ($courseId);
```

Comment: Please provide the actual raw output of `var_dump($_POST)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend you to treat an input value as an array, it's a string. You can split it on comma, example :

```html
 <option id="0" value="0,all">All</option>
```

```php
list($myInt, $myString) = explode(",", $_POST['course']);

// equivalent of 
$course = explode(",", $_POST['course']);
$myInt = $course[0];
$myString = $course[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can explode the string after you get the value:

```
<select name="course" id="course">
   <option id="0" value="" selected="" disabled="">« Please Select a Course »</option>
   <option id="1" value="0,all">All</option>
   <option id="2" value="1,Course1">Course1</option>
   <option id="3" value="2,Course2">Course2</option>
   <option id="4" value="3,Course3">Course3</option>
 </select>
```

in PHP like this:

```
$courseId = $_POST['course']; 
$arr = explode(',', $courseId);
print_r ($arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Course1
)
```